# Classification of all subgroups of $\langle\Bbb Q,+\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, rational-numbers

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2388115/328173), we know that subgroups of the rationals is either generated by one element or infinitely generated. The former case is easy to classify: $\left\langle \frac p q \right\rangle$ with $p,q \in \Bbb Z$ and $q \ne 0$.

(Note that if $p=0$, then the subgroup generated is trivial.)

Now, my conjecture is that all infinitely generated proper subgroups of $\Bbb Q$ is of the form $\Bbb Z\left[\frac 1q\right]$ with $q \in \Bbb Z \setminus \{0\}$, i.e. polynomials in $\frac 1q$ with integer coefficients, i.e. $\frac n{q^m}$ with $n \in \Bbb Z$ and $m \in \Bbb N$.

Is my conjecture correct?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{q}, \frac{1}{p}]$ ?

Comment: @Max I suspect that's isomorphic to some $\Bbb Z \left[\frac1r\right]$, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104571/how-to-find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbq.

Comment: Oh so you're looking for a classification up to isomorphism ? That's a very different job then. But even though, I'm not convinced my example would be isomorphic to one of these. In $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{q}]$, the equations $p^n x = y, q^n z=t$ have a solution for all $n, y, t$, which would not be the case in a $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{r}]$.

Comment: @Max no 'isomorphic' is actually a red-herring there.  Just  take $r = pq$. The groups are equal.

Comment: @quid : right, I didn't notice that, my bad. I "thought" too quickly, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not correct. Consider for example the subgroup generated by the set  $\{p^{-1} \colon p \text{ prime number} \}$.

Comment: That's isomorphic to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: No. It does not contain $1/4$ for example.

Comment: I think I should have asked about subrings, but I'll bear with it for now.

Comment: If you want a proper subring that is not of your form, then  consider the subring generated by $p^{-1}$ for all *odd* primes (or any other infinite set of primes).

Comment: And what about subfields?

Comment: The rationals have no proper subfield.